# Implementing polynomial operations in F#

Tags: f#

I'm given types polynomial and term defined as follow:
I want to have a function that add a term to a polynomial and keep terms, with certain degree k, less than or equals to 1. I thought I should create a function to merge terms with the same degree together and use it in addTermToPolynomial function, Here is what I have:

```
type poly=Poly of (float*int) list
type term = Term of float *int
exception EmptyList

let rec mergeCommonTerm(p:poly)=
    match p with
    |Poly [] -> Poly []
    |Poly (a::af)-> match mergeCommonTerm (Poly af) with 
                    |Poly recursivep -> 


let rec addTermToPoly (x:term, p:poly)=
    match x with
    |Term (coe, deg)-> match p with
                       |Poly[] ->  Poly [(coe,deg)]
                       |Poly (a::af)-> if snd a=deg then Poly ((fst a+coe,deg)::af)
                                       else match addTermToPoly (x,Poly af) with
                                         |Poly recusivep-> mergeCommonTerm(a::recusivep)
```

I don't know how to finish the mergeCommonTerm function because I don't know how to iterate though the list like a double for loop. Please help me write the merge like term function.

Answer (score 0):

The `term` and `poly` types are Discriminated Unions used as Records. They can easily be [unwrapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions#unwrapping-discriminated-unions) to use the underlying type (respectively `float * int` and `(float * int) list`).
You can use an auxiliary recursive function to make things easier to add a tuple to the tuple list respecting the decreasing order of degrees. This also allows to separately manage the EmptyList exception.

```
let addTermToPoly (Term (coef,deg), Poly lst) = 
    let rec loop = function
        | []           -> [(coef, deg)]
        | (c, d) :: ts ->
            if d < deg then (coef, deg) :: lst  
            elif d = deg then (coef + c, d) :: ts
            else (c, d) :: loop ts
    if (lst.IsEmpty)
    then raise EmptyList
    else Poly (loop lst) processed with loop function
```

Edit: added some comments to the example

```
// Using pattern matching in the function parameters
// allows to directly access to the underlying types
let addTermToPoly (Term (coef,deg), Poly lst) = 

    // auxiliary function to add a (float * int) tuple
    // at the right place in the list
    let rec loop = function
        // if the list is empty, retun a list containing the tuple
        | []           -> [(coef, deg)]
        // else, check the value of the head of the list
        | (c, d) :: ts ->
            // if d is lower than deg, prepend the tuple and return the list
            if d < deg then (coef, deg) :: lst  
            // if d is equal to deg, merge the tuple with the first item and return the list
            elif d = deg then (coef + c, d) :: ts
            // if d is greater than deg, prepend the first item to 
            // the result of a recursive call with the tail of the list
            else (c, d) :: loop ts

    // main function
    if (lst.IsEmpty)        // if the input lis is empty
    then raise EmptyList    // then, throw the EmptyList exception
    else Poly (loop lst)    // else, create a Poly with the list processed with loop function
```